# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing with microservices

Tags: java, microservices

I am new to the microservices + Spring Boot combinations and getting the below error while running the code from the link: https://github.com/sqshq/PiggyMetrics . Please guide me what is the nissue ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:110) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:640) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:343) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.piggymetrics.statistics.StatisticsApplication.main(StatisticsApplication.java:34) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://config:8888/statistics-service/default": config; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: config
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:607) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:130) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:81) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: config
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:80) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$BasicAuthorizationInterceptor.intercept(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:179) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2017-09-09 19:19:34.861  INFO 4968 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Learnings/micro-services/PiggyMetrics/statistics-service/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-config/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-config-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-rsa/1.0.1.RELEASE/spring-security-rsa-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.47/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47/bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-config-client/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.6/jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.6/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.6/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/oauth/spring-security-oauth2/2.0.9.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-feign/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-feign-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-commons/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-commons-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/feign/feign-core/8.16.2/feign-core-8.16.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/animal-sniffer-annotation/1.0/animal-sniffer-annotation-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/feign/feign-slf4j/8.16.2/feign-slf4j-8.16.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/feign/feign-hystrix/8.16.2/feign-hystrix-8.16.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-ribbon/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-ribbon-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon/2.1.5/ribbon-2.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon-transport/2.1.5/ribbon-transport-2.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxnetty-contexts/0.4.9/rxnetty-contexts-0.4.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxnetty-servo/0.4.9/rxnetty-servo-0.4.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxnetty/0.4.9/rxnetty-0.4.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.0.27.Final/netty-codec-http-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.0.27.Final/netty-codec-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.0.27.Final/netty-handler-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.0.27.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.0.27.Final/netty-common-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.0.27.Final/netty-buffer-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.0.27.Final/netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon-core/2.1.5/ribbon-core-2.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon-httpclient/2.1.5/ribbon-httpclient-2.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/netflix-commons/netflix-commons-util/0.1.1/netflix-commons-util-0.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon-loadbalancer/2.1.5/ribbon-loadbalancer-2.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/netflix-commons/netflix-statistics/0.1.1/netflix-statistics-0.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxjava/1.1.5/rxjava-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-archaius/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-archaius-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/archaius/archaius-core/0.7.4/archaius-core-0.7.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.1/jsr305-3.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.8/commons-configuration-1.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-eureka/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-eureka-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/eureka/eureka-client/1.4.6/eureka-client-1.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.3.7/jettison-1.3.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/netflix-commons/netflix-eventbus/0.3.0/netflix-eventbus-0.3.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/servo/servo-core/0.10.1/servo-core-0.10.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/servo/servo-internal/0.10.1/servo-internal-0.10.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.19.1/jersey-core-1.19.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.19.1/jersey-client-1.19.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-apache-client4/1.19.1/jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.0/guice-4.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/governator/governator-api/1.12.10/governator-api-1.12.10.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/eureka/eureka-core/1.4.6/eureka-core-1.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.10.30/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ec2/1.10.30/aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.10.30.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling/1.9.3/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling-1.9.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sts/1.9.3/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.9.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-route53/1.9.3/aws-java-sdk-route53-1.9.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/governator/governator/1.12.10/governator-1.12.10.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/governator/governator-core/1.12.10/governator-core-1.12.10.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.4/asm-5.0.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/4.4.1/woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon-eureka/2.1.5/ribbon-eureka-2.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.2/xstream-1.4.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.13.3/mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/1.8.4.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-stream-codec/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-codec-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-amqp/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-amqp-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/amqp/spring-rabbit/1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/amqp/spring-amqp/1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-amqp-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/http-client/1.0.0.RELEASE/http-client-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/3.5.7/amqp-client-3.5.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-amqp/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-amqp-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-jmx/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-jmx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bus/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-bus-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-stream/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-messaging-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tuple/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-tuple-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/kryo-shaded/3.0.3/kryo-shaded-3.0.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/1.3.0/minlog-1.3.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-tuple/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-integration-tuple-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/retry/spring-retry/1.1.2.RELEASE/spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/netflix/hystrix/hystrix-core/1.5.2/hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.7/HdrHistogram-2.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/pashtikar/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar]
```

Answer (score 4):

Anatoly above sums it pretty clearly and nicely as to what you need to do.
If you are looking for a quick and dirty test try changing the *hostnames*  from 
http://config:8888 to http://localhost:8888
in the bootstrap.yml files, for the service you are trying to run.

Comment: Sometime the property file you are trying to pull from config-server is invalid ( invalid yaml ) might also result in the same error.  Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

If you build and run project modules manually (e.g. from IDE) you should rename all "config" hostnames in **bootstrap.yml** files to "localhost".

The issue is, this project [uses Docker Compose](https://github.com/sqshq/PiggyMetrics#how-to-run-all-the-things) to run things

> Development mode
>
> If you'd like to build images yourself (with some changes in the code, for example), you have to clone all repository and build artifacts with maven. Then, run docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up
>
> docker-compose.dev.yml inherits docker-compose.yml with additional possibility to build images locally and expose all containers ports for convenient development.

and Docker Compose [allows you to use service name as hostname](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Answer (score 1):

Setting failsafe to false will just not throw the exception , this is something I would not recommend since this means even if you are not connected to your config server and unable to fetch the configuration your application will run which leads to an uncertain behavior (since you do not know where your properties are loaded), always better to **fail fast**.
The original cause of the problem is an exception or failing during fetching the remote environment from your config server, probably a timeout issue.

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue as the same, i resolved it by updated configuration below:

```
cloud:
    config:
        fail-fast: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is not setup properly. It thinks the hostname is 'config'.

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar, an 500 internal error from a micro service! No cause given.

I looked at the config server, for the service my application was attempting to contact.  It had given a parse error when attempting to read a yml file at start up, with the result the entire process was hanging.

So if you get an error, look in the logging data from your config server, there might be some extra information there.

Comment: Absolutely valid point to have a look at config-server logs first!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because the Jhipster Registry was not running

Answer (score 0):

After changing `Active profiles` to `local` in "Edit configuration" it started working.

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Jhipster...
The focus is on http://localhost:8761/config, and then I saw that there is a bootstrap-prod.yml based on the production environment in the project. The reason is that the configuration in the production environment is the same as the dev, which leads to an error.

So replace the produced localhost with the domain name/IP of the project registration center